# How to concat columns with 2 delimiters in hive

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

How to concat columns with 2 delimiters in hive. Please find below the input columns.

```
column1 column2 column3 column4 column5 column6 column7 column8
1        abc    dfe     ghi     jkl     mno     pqr     1
2        abc    dfe     ghi     jkl     mno     pqr     1
```

Required output concatenated string grouped by colum8 i.e., value 1.

```
1:abc:dfe:ghi:jkl-mno:pqr,2:abc:dfe:ghi:jkl-mno:pqr
```

can someone help me.

Comment: It is not clear how the data should be grouped.  Using which rules ? Min(), or row_number for example? Why column1 is taken the value from first row? please explain. What should it be if some other columns are also different?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?
First, create new columns concatenating each columns for every row then collect the concantenated columns (using collect_list) into one column by grouping them based on column8 then concatenate it (using concat_ws):

```
select concat_ws(',',
                 collect_list(concat(column1, ':', column2, ':', column3, ':', column4,':', column5, '-', column6, ':', column7
                                    )
                             )
                ) as output
from your_table
group by column8;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would write this as:

```
select concat_ws(',',
                 collect_list(concat_ws(':', column1, column2, column3, column4, column5 || '-' || column6, column7)
                             )
                ) as output
from your_table
group by column8;
```